# cells in tableview not scrolling smoothly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am almost done coding my app, but I still have a problem that I couldn't solve for weeks...I browsed on this site and other websites on the same issue, but I couldn't find a way to solve it.
I have a table view with cells (like Instagram) with images downloaded from the server. My problem is when I scroll the table view, it's not smooth and it blinks.

To construct the table view, I do the following:

-the header views and the cells are subclassed.
-I download all the images async and cache them afterwards (about 25Ko each) in the tmp folder of my app. 
-each image downloaded has the same frame as the UIImageView in which it should be placed.
-I tried to save the images in png and jpeg format, but the problem remains.

I did another test where instead of putting the downloaded images inside the cells, I put an image inside my app (with any scaling). In that case, the table view scrolls smoothly.

So I suspect maybe the problem is with the way I cache the images and get them from the cache. But even in this case, I tried to cache the images using NSCache and a temporary folder, but no result...

Here is my code:

```
-(void)CacheTheImageDownloaded: (NSData *)TheImageData : (NSString*)PathOfImage{

   NSFileHandle *fout;
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:PathOfImage contents:Nil   attributes:Nil];
   fout = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:PathOfImage];
   [fout writeData:TheImageData ];
   [fout closeFile];

}


-(UIImage*)GetTheImageFromTemporaryDirectory:(NSString*)ImagePath{
   UIImage *theCachedImage;
   theCachedImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:ImagePath];
   return theCachedImage;
}


-(void)GetImageForTheViewedCell: (NSString*) ImageName : (NSString*)TheImageURL :    (NSInteger)therow : (UIImageView*)MyImageView {

  NSString *TheKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)therow];
  NSString *tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
  NSString *ImageDownloadedTmpDir;
  ImageDownloadedTmpDir = [tmpDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TMPImagesDownloaded"];

  NSMutableString *TheImagePath = [NSMutableString stringWithString:ImageDownloadedTmpDir];
  [TheImagePath appendString:@"/"];
  [TheImagePath appendString:ImageName ];

if ( [self VerifyIfImageIsAlreadyCached:TheImagePath]){
    MyImageView.image = [self GetTheImageFromTemporaryDirectory:TheImagePath];
}
else{
    NSBlockOperation *loadImageIntoCellOp = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];
    [loadImageIntoCellOp addExecutionBlock:^(void){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),  ^{
            NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:TheImageURL];
            NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:theURL ];
            NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:data1]);
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                MyImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                NSBlockOperation *ongoingDownloadOperation =       [self.TheImageDownloadOperations objectForKey:TheKey];
                if (ongoingDownloadOperation) {
                    [self.TheImageDownloadOperations removeObjectForKey:TheKey];
                }
                [self CacheTheImageDownloaded:data :TheImagePath];
            });
        });
    }];

    if (TheKey) {
        [self.TheImageDownloadOperations setObject:loadImageIntoCellOp forKey:TheKey];
    }

    if (loadImageIntoCellOp) {
        [self.imageLoadingOperationQueue addOperation:loadImageIntoCellOp];
    }

}


}
```

I am working on Xcode 5.02.

Thanks for your suggestions!

**EDIT**

Here is my code for CellForRowAtIndexpath:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


 static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"myCustomCell";
 MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil){
     cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
 }
[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
cell.tag = row ;

//The Profile picture
NSString *theurl = self.myProfilePics[row];
NSString *TheImageName = self.TheImageNames[row];
[self GetImageForTheViewedCell:TheImageName:theurl:row: cell.ProfilePicView];  //getting image from the cache or downloaded async
[cell.TheProfilePicButton setBackgroundImage:cell.ProfilePicView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.contentView addSubview: cell.TheProfilePicButton];

//Username:
NSString *myusername = self.Usernames[row];
[cell.UsernameButton setTitle: myusername forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.contentView addSubview:cell.UsernameButton];

//date
NSString *mydate =  self.Dates[row];
[cell.DateLabel setText: mydate];
[cell.contentView addSubview: cell.DateLabel];

return cell;

}
```

Comment: can you try putting this line out of the `main_queue`? `[self CacheTheImageDownloaded:data :TheImagePath];`

Comment: Yes I will try that. But since that method is called only once per cell, when I scroll up and down many times the table view, the problem should disappear. Don't you think?

Comment: I just tried it and I did the same when getting the image from the cache...the problem still remains...:/

Comment: also make sure none of the elements/layers in the cell are using clipToBounds, this is a performance killer

Comment: I don't user clipToBounds for the cells. All the elements in the cells are created in a UItableViewCell class, and added to their subviews using cell.contentview addsubview: function

Comment: Using a test device, do Product > Analyze and select the Core Animation Instrument.  You can see your Frames Per Second, and which code is not fast enough using the Time Profiler.  (This is easier than guessing.)

Comment: Also, you may want to use SDWebImage (or compare its code to what you're doing).  That would let you simply write `[MyImageView setImageWithURL:TheImageURL];`.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I will take a look at the library

Comment: As you suggested I am using SDWebImage. It's much more efficient! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You said that 'I tried to save the images in png and jpeg format'. I suppose, you just "save to cache" the images. And you use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` in your tableview.

UITableView plays very low performance when you load many images, even if you implement "lazy load".

So, my answer is you should use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` in place of `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

**EDIT**

How about using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
CGSize imageSize = image.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

And one more, how NSCache improve performances. Here is an sample

```
@inteface YourTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) NSCache *cache;
@end

@implemetation YourTableViewController

.
.
.

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    YourCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[YourCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.yourImageView.frame = CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width - self.rowHeight)*0.5f, 0, self.rowHeight, self.rowHeight);
    }
    [cell.imageView setImage:nil];
    dispatch_queue_t globalQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(globalQueue, ^(){

        UIImage *image = [self.cache objectForKey:filePath];
        if (image == nil) {
            image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
            CGSize imageSize = image.size;
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
            [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            [self.cache setObject:image forKey:filePath];
        }

        dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^(){
            if ([[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:indexPath]) {
                YourCell *cell = (YourCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                if(image) {
                    [cell.yourImageView setImage:image];
                }
            }
        });
    });
    return cell;
}

.
.
.

@end
```

Comment: All the images downloaded are images taken on the app by the user, so I tried to save them in jpeg and png before uploading them to the server. I prefer UIImageJPEGRepresentation since I can control the quality, and reduce the weight of each image.

Comment: Can you show -cellForRowAtIndexPath: in UIViewController?

Comment: Thanks and `[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
` it looks like very bad. You shouldn't remove and re-add subviews. `UITableView` reuse subviews without allocation and just put contents on the allocated views. This is because why `UITableView` works fast. I think, you should implement `[cell.contentView addSubview:subview]` in your `Custom UITableViewCell`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! unfortunately that didn't solve it :(

Comment: Thanks! I will try to cache them the way you suggest. I will get back to you once I have tried!

Comment: Hey ryufloat! I ended up using SDWebImage, it's by far much more efficient than my method...now the scrolling is very smooth! Thanks for your help!